# How do i select old date from daterangepicker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, daterangepicker

I'm using [daterangepicker](http://www.daterangepicker.com) , and I can't select old date from second datepicker section. It shows only from this month.

[image: There is no arrow clickable on second date picker]

And There is no arrow clickable on second date picker.
I want that i can select any date , year or month on second datepicker section. There is must js code but i can't figure it out.

Here is my js code

```
$('.datepicker').daterangepicker({
  autoUpdateInput: false,
  opens: 'left',
  alwaysShowCalendars: true,
  showDropdowns: true,
  minDate: '01/01/2010',
  showOtherMonths: true,
  changeMonth: true,
  locale: {
    cancelLabel: 'Cancel'
  }
});
```

Comment: Can you give a fiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since its a daterange picker you choose a range.

I guess from the moment you choose the starting date, the ending date cannot be older than the starting one.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36753405/yii1-date-time-picker-extension-time-in-12-hour-formate